# Folders are showing as shortcut inside folders

Tags: virus-removal

Every folder in my computer has a shortcut to the same folder inside the folder.

Please see the below picture:

[image]

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I created a shortcut to refer to same folder and deleted it. There was no issue with deletion. If normal deletion don't happen then your system may be infected by Shortcut virus. I recommend you to run anti-virus S/W and disinfect your system (also external devices such as USB, Hard Disk). There are many tools for it out in internet.

If there is a case of infinite deletion fail case, then You can also try to share the main folder, access it from another system and try to delete the shortcut.Refer http://windowsforum.com/threads/folder-has-shortcut-to-itself-inside-and-will-not-delete.45151/ 
But be careful so that other system don't get infected by sharing your folder.